# I want the entire activity to be scrollable but only listview is scrollable. How do I do that?

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, android-scrollview

I pull data into my `listview` from servers. The `listview` is inside an `activity`. The `activity` has buttons above it.

When the data is received and when I scroll data, only `listview` is scrolled. The `buttons` remain fixed at the top.

I want the `listview` to take the required vertical height it needs so that I would need to scroll the `activity` instead of the `listview`.

My XML code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <TextView
                android:text="text1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/view_c_name"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <TextView
                android:text="text4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/view_c_name"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:id="@+id/view_c_motto" />

            <TextView
                android:text="text5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/view_c_motto"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:id="@+id/view_c_details" />

            <TextView
                android:text="text2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/view_c_address"
                android:layout_below="@+id/view_c_details"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            <TextView
                android:text="text3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/view_c_act_text"
                android:layout_below="@+id/view_c_address"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="71dp" />

            <Button
                android:text="Button 1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:id="@+id/view_button"
                android:layout_below="@+id/view_c_address"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            <Button
                android:text="button 2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/view_button"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/view_button"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/view_button"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:id="@+id/view_button2" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view_c_act_text"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/my_listview"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: post your xml here

Comment: I have added the XML file.

Comment: please try my ans

Comment: you just want to scroll `Buttons`  with `ListView` or `TextView` with it?

Comment: Just like facebook app home page. Consider the top stories as 'button' and 'textview' and the posts recieved from 'listview'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The perfect code should be;

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!--Inside the below layout your buttons will come. Modify it accordingly-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <!--Your buttons will come here-->

        </LinearLayout>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

As shown above, Nested Scroll View should be used instead of Scroll View because 
there is a need of scrolling view (in this case List View) inside another scrolling view. The system is unable to decide which view to scroll and this is where Nested Scroll View comes in.

Comment: Hello there. 
It did not work. It only shows one item in the list and that's it. No more items. No more scrollable.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your existing layout in a `ScrollView` to scroll the entire thing, not just the `ListView`

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- your existing layout here, change your top container's height from match_parent to wrap_content -->

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem then I created a class

```
public class ListViewExpanded extends ListView {
    public ListViewExpanded(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setDividerHeight(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST));
    }
}
```

then I used in xml as try it out it will help for sure

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
  <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_goal_scored"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          />
<example.ListViewExpanded
                android:id="@+id/list_home"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1">
</example.ListViewExpanded>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: Still, only the listview is scrollable. the activity is not :(

Comment: Can you post you xml?

Comment: @SidDharthaNeupane it will for sure check the edited code

Comment: I am not being able to do it. I can't figure out what to do with your code. What exactly should I be doing?

Comment: You should create a class called ListViewExpanded then you can use it in xml like listview you.@SidDharthaNeupane

Answer (score 0):

this is how you can do your task.this is Scroll disabled listview so you can scroll your activity easily.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.ListView;

/**
 * Created by sudesh Regmi on 4/20/2017.
 */

public class ScrollDisabledListView extends ListView {
    private int mPosition;

public ScrollDisabledListView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public ScrollDisabledListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public ScrollDisabledListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    final int actionMasked = ev.getActionMasked() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;

    if (actionMasked == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        // Record the position the list the touch landed on
        mPosition = pointToPosition((int) ev.getX(), (int) ev.getY());
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    if (actionMasked == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        // Ignore move events
        return true;
    }

    if (actionMasked == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        // Check if we are still within the same view
        if (pointToPosition((int) ev.getX(), (int) ev.getY()) == mPosition) {
            super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
        } else {
            // Clear pressed state, cancel the action
            setPressed(false);
            invalidate();
            return true;
        }
    }

    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}

@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2,
            MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);
}
}
```

Comment: Still, only the listview is scrollable. the activity is not ;(

Comment: use ScrollDiabled ListView instead of the listview. I have Attached a Class for you

Comment: How do I use the ScrollDiabled ListView instead of the listview?

Comment: copy the code and make class. and goto the xml file and use same as list view.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollViewMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/linearLayoutMain"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:orientation="vertical">

         <Button
              android:text="Button"
              android:id="@+id/buttonMain"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Still the same :'(

Answer (score 0):

```
  <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent">
      android:layout_height="match_parent">
      <ScrollView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">

       "your existing layout here, change your top container's height from match_parent or wrap_content "
```

the best case secanrio is to use scroll View inside of an relative layout and all the existing code inside of the scrollView

Comment: Height of the listview is equal to that of a list view item eventhough I tried both match_parent and wrap_content and the listview is still scrollable, the activity is not.

Answer (score 0):

> **Go through this Example. Make ScroolView as Parent. It Work Form me.**

```
     <ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/maintool"
                layout="@layout/toolbar"></include>


            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/re1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Email"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/text" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/re2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Select Email template"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinner"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/text2"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp" />
            </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
        </ScroolView>
```

Answer (score 0):

`setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(your_listview);`

add this line in your activity

```
public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
    ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
    if (listAdapter == null) {
        return;
    }
    int totalHeight = 0;
    int desiredWidth = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(), MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
        listItem.measure(desiredWidth, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
    }
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    listView.requestLayout();
}
```

add scrollview at parent in your xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/view_c_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="text1"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/view_c_motto"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/view_c_name"
            android:text="text4" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/view_c_details"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/view_c_motto"
            android:text="text5" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/view_c_address"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/view_c_details"
            android:text="text2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/view_c_act_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/view_c_address"
            android:layout_marginTop="71dp"
            android:text="text3" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/view_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/view_c_address"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:text="Button 1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/view_button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/view_button"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/view_button"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/view_button"
            android:text="button 2" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/my_listview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="700dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/view_c_act_text"
            android:scrollbars="none" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```